# VS2010 Win Form App install not running

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation

I created my first simple C# app in VS 2010.  Nothing but an application that runs a form and uses several references.  I want to put this on other machines.  What is needed to run this application besides the exe.  I am targeting .NET 4.0 and I know 4.0 is installed on the machines.  I tried to put it on  a machine but all it does is nothing.  Is there some kind of runtime I need to install besides the .NET framework.  What is required to run this Winform app.  Thanks

Comment: In case you are using 3rd party libraries, you would have to deploy them too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dump the bin\Release folder on another computer, you should be able to run it by running `<myApp>.exe` as long as the computer has the target .NET framework installed.

Comment: Got it, I also had to include third party dlls as well in the release by going to the reference and marking local copy as TRUE.